# Cannot GET /the route Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, evernote

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/mo-doors-evernote-app/) ([source code](https://hub.jazz.net/project/steven_wood/DOORS%20Next%20Generation%20Evernote%20Integration/overview?utm_source=dw&utm_medium=article&utm_content=mo-doors-evernote-app-2&utm_campaign=bluemix&cm_mc_uid=86365386312514542865707&cm_mc_sid_50200000=1456162564#https://hub.jazz.net/git/steven_wood%252FDOORS.Next.Generation.Evernote.Integration/contents/master/app.js)) and added the highlighted code.

// app.js

```
app.get("/notebooks", function(req, res) {
    var client = new Evernote.Client({ token: req.session.oauthAccessToken }),
        noteStore = client.getNoteStore();

    noteStore.listNotebooks(function(err, noteBooks) {
        res.send(err || noteBooks);
    });
});


app.get('/importNotes', function (req, res) {
    res.send('importNotes');
});


app.get("/notes/:guid", function(req, res) {
   var client = new Evernote.Client({ token: req.session.oauthAccessToken }),
        noteStore = client.getNoteStore();

    noteStore.getNote(req.params.guid, true, true, true, true, function(err, note) {
        if (!err) {
           note.content = ENML.HTMLOfENML(note.content, note.resources);
        }        
        res.send(err || note);
    });
});
```

another attempt:

```
app.get('/importNotes', function (req, res) {
    res.render('importNotes', {});
});
```

I created importNotes.html near to index.html.

After starting the server with `node app.js` 
I'm getting an error stating `Cannot GET /importNotes`
 when I access `localhost:3000/importNotes`

I plan to use this page to add additional features after I deal with this issue (import the notes from the special txt file).

What I'm doing wrong and how I can correct it?

How to define correctly the needed routes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Steve - thanks for trying out the code !

If you use this code :

```
app.get('/importNotes', function (req, res) {
    res.send('importNotes');
});
```

Then I would expect the server will send back to the browser the string "importNotes".  Perhaps if you have a file called "importNotes" there is some confusion.

If you want to create a file called importNotes.html - then just put it into the "public" folder.  It will then be accessible via localhost:3000/importNotes.html

The line :

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
```

Tells Express to serve the contents of the "public" folder at the root level of your application, so any files you put in that folder should be GETable.  e.g.

/public
   index.html
   steve.html

localhost:3000/steve.html

Comment: Steve, thanks, I renamed the page and run reload the server and both:
localhost:3000/steve.html
and
localhost:3000/importNotes
are shown.